# WordPress hard code URL structure

Tags: wordpress

OK so I am creating a WordPress plugin that requires constant URL structures. For example, the plugin has a regular cron to run and a web hook so I want the following URLs

examplesite.com/plugin/webhook/
examplesite.com/plugin/cronjob/

Is there any way I can code this into the template so that these links will always be the same throughout multiple installations?

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: I don't think so because what happens if someone's WP installation is at `example.com/blog/plugin/...` or `blog.example.com/plugin/...`
Also plugins are installed in the `INSTALLATION FOLDER/wp-content/plugins/PLUGINNAME`

Comment: @Howlin yeah I see you're point but I essentially just want WordPress to know where it can find the files, regardless of installation location. So if it was /blog/plugin/webhook/ then WordPress would be aware of that and prevent physical pages being created under this name. Perhaps a better example.. I have a stockist locator widget and I want to post that form to a certain location every time. All submissions should go to WPINSTALLURL/stockist-search/ for example where the results would be displayed.

Comment: Just considering accessing the URL directly, I can't really do that as I want to load all the appropriate WordPress connection details, classes etc. There must be a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so eventually got a solution for this and thought I should share it for future reference. It is possible to create custom rewrite rules using the `generate_rewrite_rules` [action reference](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/generate_rewrite_rules).

To achieve this, I have created the action referencing a method

`add_action('generate_rewrite_rules', 'plugin_generate_rewrite_rules')`

The plugin method is -

```
function plugin_generate_rewrite_rules($wp_rewrite) {
    // create plugin rewrite rules
    $rewrite_rules = array (
        'PLUGIN_NAME/cronjob/' => 'wp-content/plugins/PLUGIN_NAME/cronjob.php',
        'PLUGIN_NAME/webhook/' => 'wp-content/plugins/PLUGIN_NAME/webhook.php',
    );

    // apply new rewrite rules
    $wp_rewrite->non_wp_rules += $rewrite_rules;
}
```

This will work, other than the fact that the rewrite rules need to be flushed for these changes to be applied. This can be created by adding a WordPress [register activation hook](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_activation_hook) for when the plugin is activated.

```
function plugin_activate() {
    // flush rewrite rules
    global $wp_rewrite;
    $wp_rewrite->flush();
}
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'plugin_activate' );
```

I hope this helps some people!